# How to prove this bound on consecutive primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I obtained that the following bound should be true for sufficiently large (or even all) $n \in \mathbb N$ $$p_n(2-p_n)+p_{n+1}(2p_n-p_{n+1})\geq 2$$ but I do not know how to prove this.

If infinite number of twin prime-pairs exist then this bound is true for those pairs.

However, I do not know is this bound true in general?

How to prove this bound, if true (I think it is true in general)?

**Edit**: It seems that $n=4$ is the only counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always true. For example, consider $n = 4$, so $p_n = 7$ and $p_{n+1} = 11$. Your LHS then becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p_n(2 - p_n) + p_{n+1}(2p_n - p_{n+1}) & = 7(2 - 7) + 11(2(7) - 11) \\
& = 7(-5) + 11(3) \\
& = -35 + 33 \\
& = -2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

One way to analyze where your inequality does hold is to redefine the inequality using the [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap), i.e.,

$$g_{n} = p_{n+1} - p_{n} \implies p_{n+1} = p_{n} + g_{n} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Your inequality then becomes equivalent to requiring

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p_n(2 - p_n) + (p_n + g_{n})(2p_n - (p_n + g_{n})) & \ge 2 \\
2p_n - p_n^2 + (p_n + g_{n})(p_n - g_{n}) & \ge 2 \\
2p_n - p_n^2 + p_n^2 - g_{n}^2 & \ge 2 \\
2p_n - g_{n}^2 & \ge 2 \\
g_{n}^2 & \le 2p_n + 2 \\
g_{n}^2 & \le 2(p_n + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

There may be multiple cases where \eqref{eq3A} will not hold, with the one shown in \eqref{eq1A} being the first one.

Comment: well done. :) :)

Comment: it should be true for sufficiently large n i think

Comment: @Ante I agree. My argument for that would be similar to what Greg Martin's answer states, so I won't repeat it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The asserted inequality is equivalent to
$$
2p_n-(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2 \ge 2.
$$
If we knew that $p_{n+1}-p_n \le \sqrt{p_n}$, for example, then the asserted inequality would follow.

There are a few small primes for which $p_{n+1}-p_n < \sqrt{p_n}$, the largest being $p_{30}=113$ (where $p_{31}=127$). (We can check that the original assertion holds for all these primes except $p_4=7$.)

However, we certainly conjecture that $p_{n+1}-p_n \le \sqrt{p_n}$ for sufficiently large $n$, and probably for $n\ge31$. Indeed, we conjecture a much stronger bound, like $p_{n+1}-p_n \le 2(\log p_n)^2$ (with perhaps a few small exceptions).

Therefore, it is likely that $p_4=7$ is the only counterexample to the asserted inequality.

Unfortunately, we cannot prove the bound $p_{n+1}-p_n \le \sqrt{p_n}$. The closest we have come is proving that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n \le Cp_n^{0.525}$. And if there were a pair of primes this far apart, then the asserted inequality would be false.

In summary, the asserted inequality is almost certainly true (with one small exception), but nobody can prove it yet.

Comment: well done, so it should really be true for all sufficiently large n